# Printing Keypoints Descriptors

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, feature-descriptor

I would print the descriptors of a feature keypoint.
My method receive in input a vector of keypoint, and a mat descriptor for that point.
Someone know a simply solution? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For each `descriptor` matrix you have, you can simply

```
std::cout << descriptor << std::endl;
```

to print the descriptors to the console.